# Python socket.accept() exit directly

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server

These days I'm learning socket coding for Python, and I'm learning the code of multi-thread socket coding. My code of server is beneath:

```
import socket
import threading
class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.g_conn_pool = {}
        self.num = 0      
        self.address = ('', 8022)
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server_socket.bind(self.address)
        self.server_socket.listen(128)
    def accept_client(self):
        print("accept_client\n")
        while True:
            print('in')
            client_socket, info = self.server_socket.accept()
            print('client name: ' + client_socket.getsockname())
            print(client_socket, info)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.recv_msg, args=(client_socket, info))
            thread.daemon = True
            thread.start()
    def recv_msg(self, client, info)
        pass
    def start_new_thread(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.accept_client, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        print("start_new_thread")
multi_server = Server()
multi_server.start_new_thread()
```

When running the program, it seems that the program always exits at the line `client_socket, info = self.server_socket.accept()`, because the `'client name: '` is not printed. In my exception, the server should wait until some clients come to connect it after being started. However, I didn't have the opportunity to start my client program before the server program exiting quickly.

What problem causes this condition? Do I lack any codes or operations? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This code as shown does not even compile due to syntax error. Once this is fixed it does not run since  'Server' object has no attribute 'start_new_thread'. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, the code has been edited. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: What does the main thread do after `multi_server.start_new_thread()`? You made the server thread a "daemon." Why? It's not going to run for very long if the main thread doesn't do _something._